# Which way of changing a collection of JS elements is faster in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have a select all button that I want to implement. Which way is faster?

```
$('.check-box').prop('disabled', false).trigger('change');
```

Or

```
$('.check-box').each(function(index, element){
    $(element).prop('disabled', false).trigger('change');
});
```

In the UI they  do the same thing.
It seems like the second one not only selects by class name but also select each element and that's an O(MN) operation. But is it possible that the first approach is just doing exactly what the 2nd approach is doing behind the scenes (although that'll make the first approach more favorable since its less code which is faster load time)?

Comment: probably very similar and wouldn't really matter... but you could do jsperf test.

Comment: how many elements are you dealing with?

Answer (score 1):

Most jQuery methods have an internal `each` and look basically like:

```
// $.fn is where chainable methods reside 
$.fn.methodName = function(){

   // "this" is the jQuery object that contains collection of elements 
   // returned by either $(selector) or prior method in chain

   // return "this" for chaining and loop over all elements in collection
   return this.each(function(){
       // "this" is individual element instance

       // do same thing to each element here
   });
}
```

So that is how `$('.check-box').prop('disabled', false).trigger('change');` will affect all elements with `class="check-box"`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the plain JavaScript equivalent which is faster than <del>anything jQuery</del> jQuery in Chrome, ***but*** slower than jQuery in Firefox (as  charlietfl pointed out) . [jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/40519).

- Collect by class
- Iterate through each
- Change the `disabled` attribute / property
- Click each node.

The first jQuery example is faster than the second jQuery example. The most obvious difference is that `.each()` method is one step extra. `$('.check-box')` like all jQuery objects, has an internal way to iterate through itself.

#### Demo 1

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.check-box').forEach(node => { 
  node.disabled = false;
  node.click();
});
```

```html
<input class='check-box' type='checkbox' disabled>
<input class='check-box' type='checkbox' disabled checked>
<input class='check-box' type='checkbox' disabled>
<input class='check-box' type='checkbox' disabled checked>
<input class='check-box' type='checkbox' disabled>
<input class='check-box' type='checkbox' disabled checked>
```

#### Demo 2

```js
const cBox = document.getElementsByClassName('check-box');
for (let i = 0; i < cBox.length; i++) {
  cBox[i].disabled = false;
  cBox[i].click();
}
```

```html
<input class='check-box' type='checkbox' disabled>
<input class='check-box' type='checkbox' disabled checked>
<input class='check-box' type='checkbox' disabled>
<input class='check-box' type='checkbox' disabled checked>
<input class='check-box' type='checkbox' disabled>
<input class='check-box' type='checkbox' disabled checked>
```

Comment: Surprisingly just ran your jsperf in firefox twice...first jQuery method was fastest of the 3 by a few percent. Might be faster to change the property not the attribute ... `node.disabled = false`

Comment: In this case `getElementsByClassName` might be faster? https://gomakethings.com/javascript-selector-performance/

Comment: Also `forEach` is not compatibility for IE 6-8

Comment: @charlietfl indeed do you think it's V8 optimization?

Comment: @DylanCzenski I think you might be right, difference is `getElementsByClassName` returns a live HTMLCollection and `querySelectorAll` returns a "static" NodeList maybe?

Comment: Probably, but js engines are above my pay grade. They were all close so might be Firefox has something cool under the hood now too. Being self taught and never schooled on any of this stuff I don't have a strong processing background

Comment: I'm seriously surprised that jQuery.each is so much faster in Firefox - we replaced all jQuery.each with "native" equivalent and found the website significantly more responsive in Firefox (and Chrome) - I wonder if invoking `click` (which would result in a different outcome than triggering `change` I would've thought) is what's slowing down Firefox in that test